# Replacement in a json array - Angular

Tags: json, angular

I am trying to replace an object in my json web server array : If an object with a similar id is already in the json array.

This is my json array :

```
{
  "history": [
    {
      "id": 4,
      "SNS": "BockeSinoJutsu-SNS",
      "title": "BockeSinoJutsu-title",
      "DMC": "BockeSinoJutsu-DMC",
      "date": "June 15 2022"
    },
    {
      "id": 1,
      "SNS": "Rasengan-SNS",
      "title": "Rasengan-title",
      "DMC": "Rasengan-DMC",
      "date": "2022-06-18T17:43:59.708Z"
    }
  ]
}
```

And this is the json file I am comparing it to :

```
{
  "content":[
      {
        "id":1,
        "SNS":"Rasengan-SNS",
        "title":"Rasengan-title",
        "DMC":"Rasengan-DMC"
      },
      {
        "id":2,
        "SNS":"Mangekyu-SNS",
        "title":"Mangekyu-title",
        "DMC":"Mangekyu-DMC"
      },
      {
        "id":3,
        "SNS":"Chidori-SNS",
        "title":"Chidori-title",
        "DMC":"Chidori-DMC"
      }
  ]
}
```

This is what I have tried :

```
onAddHistory(history:History){
    history.date = new Date();
    console.log(history.SNS);
    this.historyService.getHistory().subscribe(
      (response:History[])=>{
        this.ExistingHistory=response.filter(x => x.id === history.id);
        console.log(this.ExistingHistory);
        if(this.ExistingHistory.length !== 0){
          this.onDeleteHistory(this.ExistingHistory.id);
          this.historyService.addHistory(history).subscribe(
            ()=>{console.log("Success !");
            this.Histories$=this.historyService.getHistory();},
            ()=>{console.log("error")}
          );
        }else{
          this.historyService.addHistory(history).subscribe(
            ()=>{console.log("Success !");
            this.Histories$=this.historyService.getHistory();},
            ()=>{console.log("error")}
          );
      }
    }
    );
    
    }
```

But I get the following error, saying that it cannot read id of undefined :

[image: Error]

The error basically says that ExistingHistory.id is undefined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JavaScript's `Array.filter()` returns a filtered **array**. You can't access `this.ExistingHistory.id` because `this.ExistingHistory` is an array, you would have to access it like so: `this.ExistingHistory[0].id`

If you want to get one value only then you should use `Array.find()`:

```
this.ExistingHistory = response.find(x => x.id === history.id);
```

If there is a chance there is more than one duplicate, then you should use a `.forEach` loop:

```
this.ExistingHistory.forEach((x) => {
   this.onDeleteHistory(x.id);
}
```

Do be warned however that you have a ton of nested subscriptions in that method, which is generally considered bad practice. I advise you to look into [RXJS](https://rxjs.dev/guide/overview)

Comment: Thank you Iptome, I was actually using the Array and requesting the id but now I see where my mistake was.